# How to add a prefix to a tablename in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

The following copy activity parameter will copy a table to it's sink location as follows

tablename_firstname_yyyyMMddhhmmss

Can someone show how modify the parameter such that it adds the letters XYZ_ to the beginning, such that it looks like the following

XYZ_tablename_firstname_yyyyMMddhhmmss

The copy parameters are as follows:

```
@concat(
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.firstname,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'.txt'
    )
```

The copy activity sink looks like the following:

[image]

The link service looks like the following

[image]

Any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood it correctly but how about just add it to the concat?

```
@concat(
    'XYZ_',
    pipeline().parameters.TableName,
    '_',
    activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.firstname,
    '_',
    formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyyMMddhhmmss'),'.txt'
    )
```